# How to reusing playwright browser context between two server?

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to reuse playwright browser context between my computer and an instance running on server. I ran playwright in persistent context mode and copied the browser_context directory over the server, but got the following error. How to resolve the issue?

```bash
[pid=2552173][err] [2552173:2552173:0117/132021.697285:ERROR:message_box_dialog.cc(146)]
Unable to show a dialog outside the UI thread message loop: 
Chromium - The profile appears to be in use by another Chromium process (15291) on another computer (Harshs-MacBook-Pro.local). 
Chromium has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted. 
If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, 
you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chromium.
```

Comment: The browser is not prepared to share the same profile directory with multiple instances.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? If it's just about avoiding authentication in your automation, then in many cases you can use the storage state approach instead of a full browser profile. For more details read: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth

Comment: Yes it is primarily saving authentication states. Thanks for pointing to the auth docs.